# In JavaScript, how can I prevent a number from being typed as the first character in a form field?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have used javascript to prevent a specific characters from being entered into a field. The function below prevents numbers from being entered. It also checks each character as it is typed and blocks it from being entered if it is a number.

```
function LettersOnly(e) {

    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    var reg = new RegExp("[A-Za-z + ']");

    return reg.test(keychar);

}
```

I want do do something similar where the user is prevented from entering a number but ONLY if it is the first character. How would I do this? Is the above code on the right track? What should my regex look like in order to pull this off?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: _"The function below prevents numbers from being entered."_ - No, it stops numbers from being _typed_ - but the user could still paste or drag'n'drop numbers.

Comment: In the end, you will have to validate the field before using it as it is difficult to fully prevent invalid data getting into the field in all the ways it could get in there besides just typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, it is difficult to prevent all ways that an input field can be manipulated (drag/drop, paste, cut, delete) and thus you will ultimately need to validate the field before using it.

That said if you want to prevent a number being typed into the first character in the field, you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (this.selectionStart === 0) {
        if (key > 48 && key < 57) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mnm4bta1/

Comment: The event `oninput` covers all cases.

Comment: @Derek - Except the field is already modified on the input event.

Comment: that's true. But what I usually do is I also do a quick check after each input and remove invalid characters. Quick enough not to slow stuff down.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
function LettersOnly(e) {    
   e.target.value= /^\D/.test(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : "";
}
```

you can also use the above function to validate that rule upon oninput(), onpaste() and other text-injecting events, not just key events. the input text would have to not be empty and not start with a digit to pass.

most browsers support oninput(), which should cover most scenarios, but you'll want to patch that back to the usual suspects (keydown, paste, change) if you're supporting legacy browsers.

NOTE:  I changed the spirit of the OP's code in order to actually stop these inputs from altering the input.

It would also be good to use html5 validation, ex:

```
 <input pattern=/^\D/ >
```

for non-js users. bonus: it covers ALL events that change the value and you don't have to handle a single event manually in js.

Comment: I would recommend using [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead also why not using just `/^\d/` instead of `/^[\D]/`

Comment: This checks a field, but doesn't actually prevent anything.  By your method, the invalid value is already in the field.

Comment: @IhabKhattab: yeah, why not? (answer updated). thanks for the idea. i think sometimes we get tunnel-vision building RegExps...

Comment: @jfriend00: yeah, i was duping the OP, but you're right. answer updated; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regx, you just test if it is a number. Since it must start with something alphanumeric, the entry is not a number. I just answered a question very similar that required some code to detect what was entered and act of it.

```
 function checkInp(value)
{
      if (isNaN(value)) {
          alert("Must input numbers");
          return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: he wants to know that it's _not_ a number... that function body could be "return value-9e9"

Comment: He says it must not start with a number so A9 is ok but 9A is not?

Comment: "I want do do something similar where the user is prevented from entering a number but ONLY if it is the first character" The function he gives us blocks all numbers he just wants to ensure that the entry does not start with, so therefore test the value as NaN meets his request in a one liner!

Comment: since the code runs on key entry it will only get the first char, if that should ne a number the NaN test will work, since the intention is to disallow the entry the test will never be 9fd it can only be 9!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex.

Try this:

```
function getCaretPosition(oField) {
  var iCaretPos = 0;
  if (document.selection) {
    oField.focus();
    var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
    oSel.moveStart ('character', -oField.value.length);
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }
  else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == '0')
    iCaretPos = oField.selectionStart;

  return (iCaretPos);
}

function LettersOnly(e){
    return getCaretPosition(e.target) === 1 && e.keyCode > 48 && e.keyCode < 58;
}
```

This should work if you bind `LettersOnly` to the `oninput` event of your input.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to check the input from a form input field.
You can not do this with a single regex if you check the characters one by one since you will only test the regex against a character.

Do you have to use javascript for this ? If it is just client-side validation, you could use the pattern attribute avaiable from HTML5 on input elements. Below an exemple : 

(Replace the point by you authorized characters if you like)

Otherwise, if you want to stick with javascript I think the function should look like this :

```
 function LettersOnly(e) {

    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    if (document.getElementById('inputfield').val.length === 0 
    && !isNaN(parseInt(keychar)))) {
        return false;
    }
    var reg = new RegExp("[A-Za-z + ']");

    return reg.test(keychar);

}
```

`document.getElementById('inputfield').val.length === 0` checks if the string from the input field is empty (i.e. we are at the the current character is the first one)
Replace or adapt the test if it is for something else than an input field of an HTML form.

`!isNaN(parseInt(keychar)))` checks if it is a number

Comment: Why use a regex and convert a numeric keycode to a string just to check if a keycode is between two values?

Comment: I based my answer on the code given in the question. Although, I agree with you it ought to be quicker if check if a keycode is between two values.